# SSL Certificate not showing correct values? "SomeCity", "SomeState"

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, fedora, openssl

I'm getting a warning with my SSL certificate - it's saying its self signed and not trusted, also that it belongs to a different domain but I've purchased it from DigiCert.

The weird thing is it shows...

```
OU = SomeOrganizationalUnit
O = SomeOrganization
L = SomeCity
S = SomeState
```

...as the parameters when looking at the certificate. I didn't choose any of these, is there something I'm missing?

I'm using apache / openssl

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hey kron, glad to see you again

Could you please double check a couple of things to make sure you're reading the right cert

- run `openssl x509 -in CERTFILE -text`, that'll show you all the information in the certificate that you bought from digicert
- Check in your config that you're pointing your daemon to the right key and certificate

If you're getting the error that the certificate is self-signed and those organizational specs it really looks like you're pointing to a default cert, or that you sent the wrong csr to Digicert

In one word, looks like a mixup :)

Comment: thanks. I think I'm going to run through all the steps again, I'll let you know how I get on

Comment: Cool, good luck :)

Comment: "In one word, looks like a mixup :)" - hit the nail on the head. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It looks very likely that you haven't replaced the self signed certificate on the server with the one that you purchased.

Answer (score 0):

Check /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf

look at the path assigned to SSLCertificateFile

...sounds like it is pointing to the default cert, as Robert suggests

Bumped this because I just had a 'duh' moment myself while setting up SSL on an Amazon EC2 instance